# Deploying Splunk Docker image fails to login

Tags: docker, splunk

I'm using `splunk/splunk` docker image with the following commands to build and run, as I learned from the [repository README](https://github.com/splunk/docker-splunk):

```
docker build --network=$DOCKER_NETWORK -t my-splunk .

docker run \
    --name=my-splunk \
    --network=$DOCKER_NETWORK \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -e SPLUNK_START_ARGS="--accept-license" \
    -e SPLUNK_PASSWORD="1234" \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -d my-splunk
```

When I open my browser on `localhost:8000`, I'm getting the Splunk login page as expected, however when typing `admin` and `1234`, I'm getting error 401:

> No users exist. Please set up a user.

Taking a look at `/opt/splunk/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf` from within the container, content looks good:

```
[user_info]
USERNAME = admin
PASSWORD = 1234
```

Full docker logs:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:17 +0300 (0:00:00.091)       0:00:00.091 ********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [include_role : splunk_upgrade] *******************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:18 +0300 (0:00:01.821)       0:00:01.913 ********

TASK [include_role : {{ splunk.role }}] ****************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:19 +0300 (0:00:00.031)       0:00:01.945 ********

TASK [splunk_common : Install Splunk] ******************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:19 +0300 (0:00:00.075)       0:00:02.021 ********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [splunk_common : Install Splunk (Windows)] ********************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:47 +0300 (0:00:28.257)       0:00:30.278 ********

TASK [splunk_common : Generate user-seed.conf] *********************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:47 +0300 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:30.320 ********
changed: [localhost] => (item=USERNAME)
changed: [localhost] => (item=PASSWORD)

TASK [splunk_common : include_tasks] *******************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:47 +0300 (0:00:00.377)       0:00:30.697 ********
included: /opt/ansible/roles/splunk_common/tasks/enable_s2s_port.yml for localhost

TASK [splunk_common : Enable the Splunk-to-Splunk port] ************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:47 +0300 (0:00:00.062)       0:00:30.759 ********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [splunk_common : include_tasks] *******************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:50 +0300 (0:00:02.733)       0:00:33.492 ********
included: /opt/ansible/roles/splunk_common/tasks/start_splunk.yml for localhost

TASK [splunk_common : Start Splunk] ********************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:50 +0300 (0:00:00.054)       0:00:33.547 ********
changed: [localhost]

TASK [splunk_common : include_tasks] *******************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:57 +0300 (0:00:07.214)       0:00:40.761 ********
included: /opt/ansible/roles/splunk_common/tasks/add_splunk_license.yml for localhost

TASK [splunk_common : Download Splunk license] *********************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:57 +0300 (0:00:00.056)       0:00:40.818 ********

TASK [splunk_common : Set downloaded license location] *************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:57 +0300 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:40.855 ********

TASK [splunk_common : Set local license location] ******************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:57 +0300 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:40.889 ********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [splunk_common : Apply Splunk license] ************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:58 +0300 (0:00:00.043)       0:00:40.933 ********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/opt/splunk/bin/splunk", "add", "licenses", "-auth", "admin:1234"], "delta": "0:00:01.050830", "end": "2018-10-07 17:39:59.189296", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 4, "start": "2018-10-07 17:39:58.138466", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "missing PATH-TO-LICENSE-FILE argument: ./splunk add license [PATH-TO-FILE] ", "stdout_lines": ["missing PATH-TO-LICENSE-FILE argument: ./splunk add license [PATH-TO-FILE] "]}
...ignoring

TASK [splunk_common : Set as license slave] ************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:59 +0300 (0:00:01.213)       0:00:42.146 ********

TASK [include_role : splunk_search_head] ***************************************
Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:59 +0300 (0:00:00.031)       0:00:42.178 ********

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=10   changed=5    unreachable=0    failed=0

Sunday 07 October 2018  17:39:59 +0300 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:42.226 ********
===============================================================================
splunk_common : Install Splunk ----------------------------------------- 28.26s
splunk_common : Start Splunk -------------------------------------------- 7.21s
splunk_common : Enable the Splunk-to-Splunk port ------------------------ 2.73s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 1.82s
splunk_common : Apply Splunk license ------------------------------------ 1.21s
splunk_common : Generate user-seed.conf --------------------------------- 0.38s
include_role : {{ splunk.role }} ---------------------------------------- 0.08s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.06s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.06s
splunk_common : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.05s
include_role : splunk_search_head --------------------------------------- 0.05s
splunk_common : Set local license location ------------------------------ 0.04s
splunk_common : Install Splunk (Windows) -------------------------------- 0.04s
splunk_common : Download Splunk license --------------------------------- 0.04s
splunk_common : Set downloaded license location ------------------------- 0.03s
include_role : splunk_upgrade ------------------------------------------- 0.03s
splunk_common : Set as license slave ------------------------------------ 0.03s
===============================================================================

Ansible playbook complete, will begin streaming var/log/splunk/splunkd_stderr.log
```

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue at https://github.com/splunk/docker-splunk/issues with more details on docker version, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the password must be up to some default requirements, from https://hub.docker.com/r/splunk/splunk/:

> For a basic standalone Splunk environment, run the following command:
>
> $ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -e 'SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license'
>   -e 'SPLUNK_PASSWORD=' splunk/splunk:latest Note: The password supplied must conform to the default Splunk Enterprise
>   password requirements*

After changing the password from '1234' to '12345678910', login worked fine (only default requirement that matters is password length should be at least 8 characters).

Since this failure to create user is silenced, and since this is only documented in dockerhub but not in github, I will open a case to notify them.